# Relationship between the derivative of a matrix and its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices, real-analysis

Is there any relationship between the derivative of a matrix and its eigenvalues? If, for example, the derivative is strictly positive definite, can I say that the eigenvalues are strictly increasing?
In particular, my matrix is
$$-\frac{ik}{4\pi} I + \mathrm{diag}[a_1,\ldots,a_n]+A(k)$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, $\alpha_i$ are real constants and
$$ [A(k)]_{jj}=0 $$ 
$$ [A(k)]_{jl}= -\frac{e^{ik|y_j-y_l|}}{4\pi|y_j-y_l|}\quad \text{for } j\neq l $$
with each $y_i$ a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by a derivative of a matrix, since as defined they are not functions.

Comment: I have a matrix wich depends by a parameter $k$; so I have to derive the entries to respect to $k$.

Comment: If I understand well, your matrix is really explicit and of size 3. Have you tried computations, either symbolic with a CAS, or numerical ? That may give you a good idea of what is happening. (Maybe plot the eigenvalues against k, for some particular points y ?)

Comment: My matrix is square of size $n$; I don't have tried any calculation because in the book where I'm studying the author invokes the calculation of the derivative of the matrix, but I don't really understand his reasoning.

Comment: What's $i$? Is this $\sqrt{-1}$? Then it what sense your derivative 
is positive-definite?

Comment: Sorry for posting this as an answer, I cannot leave comment. Are you sure your matrix is $$[A(k)]_{j\,l}= -\frac{e^{ik|y_j-y_l|}}{4\pi|y_j-y_l|}\, j\neq l$$ and not $$[A(k)]_{j\,l}= -\frac{e^{ik|y_j-y_l|}-1}{4\pi|y_j-y_l|}\, j\neq l$$ If you want to extend some properties of the derivative of a matrix to its eigenvalue, the eigenvectors have to be independent of the derivation variable.

Comment: I'm sure that the matrix I've written is correct. 
I want to know if it is invertible and so if it has no zero eigenvalue; it should be that if $k<0$ the matrix can have a zero eigenvalue.

Comment: Do you have additional information on the $\alpha_i$ or they are of general form?

Comment: They are general

Comment: I don't see how to make further progress, could you give the reference of the book you've mentioned?

Comment: "Solvable models in quantum mechanics" by S.Albeverio

Comment: which page are you looking at?

Comment: Page 116 theorem 1.1.4

Answer (score 6):

The relation you are looking for is in the article "On Eigenvalues of Matrices Dependent on Parameter" by P.Lancaster (1964), theorem 5.
It states, that for any matrix $A$:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \lambda^{(j)}_t}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{ y_t^{(j)T} A'_t x^{(j)}_t }{ y_t^{(j)T} x^{(j)}_t }
$$
For real parameter $t$ and $y^{(j)}_t$, $x^{(j)}_t$ being left and right eigenvectors of $A_t$ corresponding to j-th eigenvalue $\lambda^{(j)}_t$.

If $A_t$ is additionally symmetric, then $y^{(j)}_t = x^{(j)}_t$ and it can be chosen real-valued. If also $A'_t$ is positive definitive, then the right side of equation is strictly positive and so is the derivative of eigenvalue.

In your particular case in the book you mentioned $k$ is set: $k=i\chi$ and $\chi$ is real-valued parameter.

Comment: Theorem 5 assumes that the eigenvalues $\lambda_{t}^{(j)}$ are simple. It is possible to generalize this result to multiple eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2):

Look at:
Andreas Kriegl, Peter W. Michor, Armin Rainer: Denjoy-Carleman differentiable perturbation of polynomials and unbounded operators. Integral Equations and Operator Theory 71,3 (2011), 407-416, [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/DC-perturb.pdf).

There is an overview on available results.